# I can't run a flask command from the terminal

Tags: python, flask

So Im doing a fantistic "course" on flask api development, and the instructor made these commands to create a database and seed it.

Those methods do not work for me for some reason! I know have to be in the virtuel enviremont, and I think I am. Not sure tho.

I have tried to look around, but for some reason I can't find anything on it!

## I get this error when running the command:

```
$flask db_create
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.

Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'db_create'.
```

And this error message does not really say anything imo, maybe Im overseeing something. I ONLY have one file code atm.

## Here is my code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'planets.db')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.cli.command('db_create')
def db_create():
    db.create_all()
    print("Database created!")


@app.cli.command('db_drop')
def db_drop():
    db.drop_all()
    print('Database dropped!')


@app.cli.command('db_seed')
def db_seed():
    mercury = Planet(planet_name='mercury',
                     planet_type='Class D',
                     home_star='Sol',
                     mass=3.258e23,
                     radius=1516,
                     distance=35.98e6)

    venus = Planet(planet_name='venus',
                   planet_type='Class K',
                   home_star='Sol',
                   mass=4.867e24,
                   radius=3760,
                   distance=67.24e6)

    earth = Planet(planet_name='Earth',
                   planet_type='Class M',
                   home_star='Sol',
                   mass=5.972e24,
                   radius=3959,
                   distance=29.96e6)

    db.session.add(mercury)
    db.session.add(venus)
    db.session.add(earth)

    test_user = User(first_name='William',
                     last_name='Hershal',
                     email='test@test.com',
                     password='password')

    db.session.add(test_user)
    db.session.commit()
    print('Database seeded!')


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():  # put application's code here
    return "hallo world"


@app.route("/super_simple")
def super_simple():
    return jsonify(message="Hallo from super simple! This is amazing!")


@app.route("/not_found")
def not_found():
    return jsonify(message='That resource was not found'), 404


@app.route('/parameters')
def parameters():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    age = int(request.args.get('age'))

    if age < 18:
        return jsonify(message="Sorry " + name + ', you are not old enough'), 401
    else:
        return jsonify(message='Welcome ' + name + ', you are old enough!')


@app.route('/url_variable/<string:name>/<int:age>')
def url_variables(name: str, age: int):
    if age < 18:
        return jsonify(message="Sorry " + name + ', you are not old enough'), 401
    else:
        return jsonify(message='Welcome ' + name + ', you are old enough!')


# database models
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)


class Planet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'planets'
    planet_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    planet_name = Column(String)
    planet_type = Column(String)
    home_star = Column(String)
    mass = Column(Float)
    radius = Column(Float)
    distance = Column(Float)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Please help me out!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66716267/lask-cli-noappexception-while-importing-app-an-importerror-was-raised

Comment: I have tried that, and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

## The stupid mistake

I thought that I was in the venv, since I was told that PyCharm did that by it self by the instructor.

So if any have any problem like that, I fixed it by doing:
`source venv/bin/activate.fish` 
To note, it is only activate.fish because I use the fish terminal, so you might need to choose another file.